# how to resolve conflict of webpack in specific port (vue.js)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, npm, webpack, port

I use npm webpack in vue.js project.

```
npm run dev
```

In webpack.dev.conf.js, I use proxy table.

```
proxy: {
  "/api": {
    target:"http://localhost:5000",
    changeOrigin: true
  }
},
```

It worked well, but now I can't.

Once I changed proxy url to https://my-domain.com, and it never works.

I rolled back to "http://localhost:5000", but error message says proxy can't access to https://my-domain.com.

For reference, I ran it again(npm run dev) whenever I changed it.

And it doesn't work at 8080 port, but it works well at 8082 port. How can I resolve conflict of webpack for specific port?

Comment: You can try deleting `node_modules/.cache` folder. Also, check that you can access `https://my-domain.com/api/xxxxx` directly from a browser (e.g. using Postman or Postwoman)

Comment: I can't find node_modules/.cache folder.  And I can access https://my-domain.com/api/blahblah by Postman, Insomnia and 8082 port browser.

I received a new project from git repository, it's same..

Comment: Did you use HTTPS in Postman ? Do you have another proxy running at 8080 ? Is your router doing transparent SNAT to port 8080 ?

Comment: I solved it. I cleared cache files of chrome browser. And it works well. Thanks for your answers.